# How to provide API key when using Topic API of Freebase

Tags: freebase

I am trying to use the new googleapi for Freebase Topic API as the old one is going to get deprecated. I would like to use my API key in the query as I am getting a 403 error of limit.

I am trying like this: `https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/03zf5vc&key=some_key` 
but this does not seem to work.

Can someone please tell me what the correct syntax is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amersands (&) are used to separate parameters, but a question mark (?) is needed to separate the query from the address

Try

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/03zf5vc?key=some_key
```

Comment: Feel free to accept it as the correct answer if it solves your problem and/or vote it up.